# TensorBoard: Can I display a large GraphDef - eg. 1000 step unrolled RNN Seq2Seq

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm having an issue with TensorBoard displaying large GraphDef - eg. 1000 step unrolled RNN Seq2Seq graph

As point of reference via write_graph, GraphDef.bin is ~288MB.

When selecting the GRAPHS tab in TensorBoard, progress bar shows:
Data: Parsing graph.pbtxt (about 2min)
Data: Parsing graph.pbtxt (>12hours, seems to be stalled)

Any tips on how to debug the Parsing graph.pbtxt, or the load process in Chrome browser?

Ideally it would be nice to include "run_metadata" to look at compute/memory but, for starters it would be nice to at least visualize the graph.

Comment: How big is the graph.pbtxt (not the .bin file)? Since all of rendering/layout/data structures are in the browser, graphs bigger than 200MB will usually end up allocating more than 1.9GB of memory (memory limit in Chrome per tab) at which point the tab might freeze.

Comment: pbtxt for the model that wasn't loading was about 380MB.  The graph_def.pbtxt for our current model is about 986M.  I'll see if I can increase the per tab memory limit and retry.  Thank you!